# SFML вращение спрайта

Tags: разработка-игр, sfml

Как задать угол вращения спрайта, чтобы он не съезжал/не пропадал. Хочу в игре сделать чтобы стены, пол и тп имели спрайты, которые рандомно повернуты для разнообразия текстур. Сделал рандом из массива (0, 90, 180, 270). В итоге получается что вращение происходит не вокруг оси центра спрайта, а черт знает как, получается каша заместо стены.

Comment: Чтобы указать центр вращения спрайта надо использовать метод setOrigin(float x , float y)

Comment: спасибо. разобрался. для каждого угла нужен свой оригин, в моем случае 4 варианта угла и 4 варианта оригина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал нужный эффект:

```
void Cell::setRotationBaseSprite()
{

    int rotationAngles[4] = {0, 90, 180, 270 };
    int angle = rotationAngles[rand() % 4];

    switch (angle)
    {
    case 0:
         _baseTile->setOrigin(0, 0);
        break;
    case 90:
        _baseTile->setOrigin(0, 32);
        break;
    case 180:
        _baseTile->setOrigin(32, 32);
        break;
    case 270:
        _baseTile->setOrigin(32, 0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    _baseTile->rotate(angle);   

}
```